# WireMock and Feign problem (Unit tests, Spring)

Tags: java, spring, wiremock, feign

I'm trying to write some unit tests for few funcionts, which used feign to get information from another service. I try to use WireMock to do it but unfortunetely i get an exception like this :

```
feign.RetryableException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:8088/... executing POST http://localhost:8088/api

    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:249)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.info(Unknown Source)
    at nbs.mobile.cashdesk.be.adapters.XXX.service.XXXAdapter
    at nbs.mobile.cashdesk.be.application.service.XXX
    at nbs.mobile.cashdesk.be.adapters.web.device.DeviceControllerTest.exampleTest(DeviceControllerTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:75)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:8088/...
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:236)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:169)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:242)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:213)
    ... 58 more
```

TestFunciton:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class XXXTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(8087, 8088);

    @Rule
    public WireMockClassRule instanceRule = wireMockRule;

    @Autowired
    private XXXClass xxxClass;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        WireMock.reset();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        wireMockRule.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/api"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withStatus(200).withBody("{\"token\":\"1234\"}/n")))
        ;
        log.error("Server Start");
        log.error(wireMockRule.toString());
        log.error(wireMockRule.getStubMappings().toString());

        xxxClass.xxx("3214"); // This function is tested
        
        assertEquals("12", "12");
    }

}
```

I think that this information is enaugh to know something about this problem (I could add that it works fine with real services so in my opinion problem is somewhere in MockServer configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close your resulting json

```
.withStatus(200).withBody("{\"token\":\"1234\"/n")))
```

should be

```
.withStatus(200).withBody("{\"token\":\"1234\"}/n")))
```

Comment: mistake in question

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change port of mock server.